# How to makes datasource truly unchangable?

Tags: axapta

I have datasource on a form created by code.

```
 formBuildDataSource = form.addDataSource("My_table");
```

than I open a detail which has datasource from same table and dynamic link and same data row. When I change something od detail and than run

```
getFirstSelection(formCaller.dataSource(1));
```

I do not get old data but the new modified data. Is there a way how to get old data from base form before this modification? Somehowmake data datasource on old form unchangable (for whole existence of form).

When I set

```
formBuildDataSource.autoQuery(false);    
formBuildDataSource.autoSearch(false);
```

than I see no data on a first form. So it would be nice to do something like:

```
formBuildDataSource.getData();
formBuildDataSource.autoQuery(false);    
formBuildDataSource.autoSearch(false);
```

The Args.record(...) is used for something else so it would be nice to do not need to use it.

I am using AX 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't very clear what you are trying to achieve. If, after modifying a record, you want to check what values its fields had before the change ("Is there a way how to get old data from base form before this modification"), you could have made a copy of the original record before making the changes, e.g.

```
MyTable myTableOrig = myTable.data();
```

or if you don't need system fields then

```
MyTable myTableOrig;
buf2Buf(myTable, myTableOrig);
```

After that you can always compare current myTable field values and original field values copied to myTableOrig.

Comment: The whole thing is made in x++ code and I do not know how too add variable to the form which is created by form = new Form();

Comment: And I do not know how to access the variable created in class definition of form created by form = new Form("Form");